# Problem with iptables - can't DNAT or use --dport

Tags: iptables

I have been having a few frustrating hours trying to get iptables to work. I have updated and upgraded my raspbian. I have iptables V1.4.14 installed.

```
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT         
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I get the same if I try a DNAT instruction. I found reference to the file below - which looks pretty minimal:

```
# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_targets                                       
MASQUERADE
ERROR
```

This is my current configuration:

```
#iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.192.128.0/17      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It seems pretty basic what I think I am trying to do, maybe I'm missing something basic?

Answer (score 1):

So, after more research, I found someone that had a similar problem (http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=8429&), part of their resolution was to load the xt_tcpudp module. 
This led me in a different direction - I found I was having issues with modprobe. uname -a showed a level of 3.10.25, however there was no lib/modules/3.10.25+ - the directory in modules was several revisions higher.
I tried using rpi-updater to straighten things out. Still no joy, in fact it seemed to break some other things. lsmod showed nothing loaded.
So, today I used rpi-updater with the git sha of the 3.10.25 commit to reinstall the 3.10.25 version.
After this, iptables now seems to work fine, lsmod shows a bunch of modules loaded.

Hope this may help someone else out one day :)